# How to use the verb "fall" in a passive sentence?

Tags: phrase-usage

I need to transform active sentences into passive sentences, using the verb *to fall*.

For instance, for

> My talk falls naturally into three parts.

could we say

> My talk is felt into three parts.

---

Would you please show me if we can use each of the following as a *passive sentence*? Would you please elaborate your explanations?

---

- We don’t want this information to fall into the wrong hands.
- She fell into modelling quite by accident.
- She fell into a conversation with the taxi driver.
- Over the years the house had fallen into disrepair.
- My talks falls naturally into three parts.

Comment: There seems to be an inconsistency, due to a typo. Do you mean "My talks fall", or "My talk falls"? Both would be correct, but "My talks falls" is not.

Answer (score 4):

The word fall is an intransitive verb; it has no object.  So you cannot change any of these sentences into the passive voice.

Answer (score 1):

The verb "fall" can not clearly be used in active voice sense as the subject does nothing to perform the action of falling. Though "fall" is an action verb, the action of falling is acted upon the subject.
Not only "fall" but there are also few other verbs considered as action verbs and used in passive sense but the action described by the verb is acted upon the subject of the sentence or the verb is describing what happened to the subject.
Few examples
A man climbing a palm tree **fell** from that tree.
One of my friends **died** on the road.
Suddenly I **felt** alone in the deserted road.

Answer (score -1):

Subject matters:

> It falls to be aired = It needs to be aired, looked at

Comment: Please add explanation to your answer. Also, the question is in need of clarification, kindly take note. Thank you!